# Downloads stop half way on Windows over Ethernet

Tags: windows, networking, download, ethernet, stall

**EDIT**: The problem *does* occur with the wifi as well as ethernet. It was just harder to spot.

I have an X99 Deluxe motherboard with two ethernet ports. Using either of the ports, or the built-in wifi, on Windows 10 Pro, downloading large files over the internet (ADSL connection via a gigabit router and ADSL modem) always fails after approximately 90MiB - the download speed slows to 0 bytes/s and never recovers.

This issue occurs on all large downloads, whether it is `wget` inside a Linux virtual machine, or a Chrome download.

I do *not* experience this issue if:

- I use Ubuntu Linux which is installed on another partition
- I transfer files locally from my laptop (which runs Ubuntu)

I have tried:

- Reinstalling Windows
- Installing the latest network drivers from Asus
- Using a different network cable and port on the router

Clearly this is some bug in Windows, but I have no idea what?

Comment: If it happens within a Linux virtual machine then it can't be a bug with Windows since it also happens within a Virtual Machine.

Comment: But the virtual machine is attached to a NAT so all traffic is passed through Windows, is it not?

Comment: I suppose.   Doesn't mean its a bug in Windows 10 and not the device driver though.

Comment: Run http://netalyzr.icsi.berkeley.edu/ and post the results (or a link to the results if you're not paranoid)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly an answer, but I can't list this clearly in a comment.

Process of elimination needs to happen now.

Things to try. In all of these, you're just eliminating possible causes of the problem. So if the problem goes away after you do each of these steps then it can be reliably assumed that whatever you removed from the equation was the cause of the problem:

- Disable the NATing if possible without negatively affecting your internet connection - eliminates the NAT as a cause
- Connect through a different router - eliminates the router as a cause
- Change the source of your internet connection (try it with an LTE device or something) - eliminates your physical DSL line / fibre connection as a cause
- If you can, try to see whether the problem persists on other computers connected to the network. If it doesn't, its most likely something wrong with your ethernet device or else the software on your computer is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

I enabled QoS on the router and the issue went away.

Also, I found out that on a separate desktop PC, I could also reproduce the issue (again, on Windows but not on Ubuntu or Gentoo Linux). So it is something to do with Windows' default network settings.

I suspect it has something to do with overloading the router or modem.